# How to read WCF Soap Response from WCF Server Code?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have looked through all of the related posts I could find on this site and I have scoured the Internet...and I am stumped about how to read a WCF's SOAP response before it sends it back to the client.

I want to read the response in its final form (with the soap envelop elements included in the XML) and send it to my custom log procedure.

Note that I have to  use a custom log function provided that accepts the response as a string and sends it to a SQL db (not shown). This has to be handled by the code at runtime for each response; I can't simply use some 3rd party logging/tracer tool.

Here is my WCF service code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using MSADataAccess;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace svcIDIVS
{
    public class VINS : IVINS
    {

        public string VerifyInsurance(string coverageRequest)
        {
            string responseMessage = null;
            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
            responseMessage = da.VerifyInsurance(coverageRequest);
            return responseMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to read responseMessage along with its SOAP Envelope into a string. It should look something like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <VerifyInsuranceResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <VerifyInsuranceResult>&lt;CoverageResponseDocument PublicationVersion="00200809" PublicationDate="2008-11-05" xmlns="http://www.iicmva.com/CoverageVerification/"&gt;  
    &lt;Detail&gt;  
        &lt;PolicyInformation&gt;  
            &lt;CoverageStatus&gt;  
                &lt;ResponseDetails&gt;  
                    &lt;ResponseCode&gt;Unconfirmed&lt;/ResponseCode&gt;  
                    &lt;UnconfirmedReasonCode&gt;VIN2&lt;/UnconfirmedReasonCode&gt;  
                &lt;/ResponseDetails&gt;  
            &lt;/CoverageStatus&gt;  
            &lt;OrganizationDetails&gt;   
                &lt;NAIC&gt;14788&lt;/NAIC&gt;  
                &lt;!-- this can be echoed from the request or provide the actual NAIC that has evidence of coverage --&gt;  
            &lt;/OrganizationDetails&gt;  
            &lt;PolicyDetails&gt;  
                &lt;!-- this section can be echoed from the request --&gt;  
                &lt;VerificationDate&gt;07/16/2008 00:00:00&lt;/VerificationDate&gt;  
                &lt;PolicyKey&gt;03K85845&lt;/PolicyKey&gt;  
                &lt;PolicyState&gt;CT&lt;/PolicyState&gt;  
            &lt;/PolicyDetails&gt;  
        &lt;/PolicyInformation&gt;  
    &lt;/Detail&gt;  
&lt;/CoverageResponseDocument&gt;  
</VerifyInsuranceResult>
    </VerifyInsuranceResponse>
  </s:Body>
```

Answer (score 1):

WCF has [Message Dispatcher Inspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx) wherein you can intercept messages and validate prior to send/reply for your service.

```
public class BodMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            return instanceContext;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            // DO your stuff here and validate your reply Message
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see this code all over the place but I could not figure out how to pass in the existing parameters that my service code is using. How does my service code shown above get the existing Message and correlationState to pass into BeforeSendReply ?